# Display PiCamera video to an embedded video player in a python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, raspberry-pi3

Is there any way of embedding a video player into the GUI of a python program and then displaying video from a piCamera to it in real time?

Currently, when I preview it fills the whole screen and makes any GUI unusable.

I would like to overlay information over the video capture.

I'm not too hot on Python but on Visual Studio for example you could use the VLC plug-in and use it as a display component.

There's lots of tutorials about how to host video and stream it to a server but nothing covers local display.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but I use RPi-Cam-Web-Interface.  If you are not aware of it you may want to take a look: http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface